# Google sheets button with "assigned script" disappears

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with several scripts attached to images as buttons being used by lots of people. The weird thing is, there's a set of three buttons in each workbook, and one of them (the same one each time) always "loses" the assigned script and just becomes an image again.

I've been unable to figure out what causes the script to become "unattached" from the image. I can't share the specific sheet here since it has sensitive info, but I could mock a similar one up if it's helpful. Mostly wondering if anyone knows what causes scripts to dissociate from buttons. My only theory is that script triggers might cause it, so I just turned triggers off and we'll see how that goes the next few days.

Thanks and apologies for vague question!

```
function tabs() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      t = s.getSheetByName('Tabs'),
      n = s.getSheets()
      .map(function(s, i) {
        return [s.getName()]
      });
  t.getRange('A1:A').clear();
  t.getRange(1, 1, n.length, 1).setValues(n)
}
```

Comment: Can you at least share the script? If you believe that won't help much, create a new spreadsheet copy the script there and then share the sheet with no sensitive data.

Comment: Should have thought of that! I added the script code in. It just grabs all the tabnames in the sheet and pops them into the "Tabs" sheet. If it's any help, it's the "first" button in the workbook, but I don't see why that would cause issues.

Comment: Under what conditions are the linkings lost? Is it whenever you load the sheet? every day?

Comment: Haven't quite been able to pinpoint it. It does not seem to be time-gated, nor specifically tied to opening the sheet after it's been closed. It might be something to do with multiple people using the sheet, but it's weird because the other two script buttons "stick" just fine. The only definitive way I can reproduce the issue is by right-clicking the button and pulling down the menu options, going to to "assign script...", then "canceling" without changing the script assignment or clearing it. It then dissociates every time. This ALSO happens to the other buttons though, so isn't the issue.

Comment: I renamed the function to be named identically to the script "file name" itself and changed the structure of the code a bit to be more uniform to the way I'd done the other scripts. So far ~4 days later this is helping, haven't had this issue since. My only remaining theory is that this is caused by multiple people accessing and editing the spreadsheet at once somehow - a theory which will be tested on Monday when folks log in again to use it en masse.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing same issue. So, I added OnOpen(e) event as below with plugin showing with required Menu. This resolved the issue.

```
function onOpen(e) {    
    var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp.
    if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
        // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
        menu.addItem('Update Master List', 'Prepare_Lists_Data');
    } else {
        // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
        var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
        var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
        if (workflowStarted) {
        menu.addItem('Update Master List', 'Prepare_Lists_Data');
        } else {
        menu.addItem('Update Master List', 'Prepare_Lists_Data');
        }
        menu.addToUi();
    }
}
```